# FullTextSearch indexing/searching words with special characters

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I'm trying to query FullTextSearch indexed column for hashtags

```
SELECT Bio FROM Users
WHERE CONTAINS (Bio,'promoter')

SELECT Bio FROM Users
WHERE CONTAINS (Bio,'#promoter')
```

both results returns the same record

```
promoter of #Art
```

I tried also to put double quotes around the searched term `"#promoter"` but same result.

The same problem when I'm searching for `'@something'`

What I need to do in order FullTextSearch to index the special characters?

Comment: Try `'"@something"'` or `'"#promoter"'`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I tried, its written in the question

Comment: Question says about `"#Promoter"` instead I am saying about `'"#promoter"'` single quotes than double quotes and than search term

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Yes, using only double quotes is invalid syntax.